# Toggling Primary and Secondary Camera

Tags: android

I am developing an app, which has camera feature. It is working fine. I was wondering how should I can use the front facing camera, if the phone has one. I should be able to toggle between primary and secondary cameras.

Answer (score 1):

[As explained in the Camera guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#detect-camera) you need to check for the number of cameras, then use `Camera.open(int)`.